# How to read file with cyrillic characters in the filename in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, filepath

I am trying to read image file with filenames having cyrillic characters.

```
ls /home/atin/test
ОД Д.bmp
```

Now I am trying to read 'ОД Д.bmp' in python 3

```
image_path='/home/atin/test/ОД Д.bmp'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sample_image=plt.imread(image_path)
```

But I get this error.

```
SystemError: <built-in function read_png> returned NULL without setting an error
```

But `os.listdir('/home/atin/test')` gives following output

['\udcd0\udc9e\udcd0\udc94 \udcd0\udc94.bmp']

How can I decode the above output to original file name which is ОД Д.bmp.
I am using python 3.6 in ubuntu here.

Comment: `ОД р1` is not the same thing as `ОД Д`. The error doesn't immediately indicate to me that the filename was the issue here.

Comment: What does [`sys.getfilesystemencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) return? That may be a wrong value. What operating system is this?

Comment: Those `\u` escape sequences are low surrogate points. This may indicate that the filesystem encoding is not UTF-8 but Python is expecting UTF-8. The bytes are then preserved via the *surrogateescape* error handler, but that'd mean the original data was `b'\xd0\x9e\xd0\x94 \xd0\x94.bmp'`, which is *valid UTF-8*.

Comment: I have made the necessary edit, sorry for the wrong input. But still the error is the same.

Comment: What does the UNIX command `locale` produce? That is almost certainly wrong, for the given filesystem.

Comment: sys.getfilesystemencoding() returns 'ascii'.

Comment: `locale` gives following output. 

`locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_SG.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_SG:en
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_SG.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_SG.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_SG.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_SG.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_SG.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_SG.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_SG.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_SG.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_SG.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_SG.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_SG.UTF-8"
LC_ALL= `

Comment: Note the *Cannot set LC_CTYPE* error in there. `LC_CTYPE` is the *crucial component* for the filesystem encoding. You have `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8`, with no locale name, which is invalid. Set `LC_CTYPE=en_SG.UTF-8` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system has an incorrect locale configured. On Linux, Python takes the filesystem codec from the locale. From the [`sys.getfilesystemencoding()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding):

> Return the name of the encoding used to convert between Unicode filenames and bytes filenames.
>
> [...]
>
> - On Unix, the encoding is the locale encoding.

You have a filesystem that uses UTF-8 but Python is not reading the data correctly.

As a result, the UTF-8 data can't correctly be decoded, there is an decoding error, and the [`surrogateescape` error handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) kicks in, and it has 'preserved' the bytes as [low surrogate codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF).

You can reverse the issue by encoding to UTF-8 with the same error handler:

```
>>> '\udcd0\udc9e\udcd0\udc94 \udcd0\udc94.bmp'.encode('utf8', 'surrogateescape')
b'\xd0\x9e\xd0\x94 \xd0\x94.bmp'
```

The result happens to be the correct UTF-8 encoding for your filename:

```
>>> '\udcd0\udc9e\udcd0\udc94 \udcd0\udc94.bmp'.encode('utf8', 'surrogateescape').decode('utf8')
'ОД Д.bmp'
```

You'll want to use `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` *at the very least*, to avoid this issue. In your case you appear to have `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8`, which is invalid (you could use `LC_CTYPE=en_SG.UTF-8` instead).

Another work-around is to use *bytes* paths:

```
image_path = '/home/atin/test/ОД Д.bmp'.encode('utf8')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however `image_path = '/home/atin/test/ОД Д.bmp'.encode('utf8')` still doesn't work, I am getting an error `SystemError: <built-in function read_png> returned NULL without setting an error`

Comment: @AtinGhosh: presumably then `plt.imread()` decodes the path again.

Comment: Sorry actually `image_path = '/home/atin/test/ОД Д.bmp'.encode('utf8')` works, but when I try `plt.imread('/home/atin/test/ОД Д.bmp'.encode('utf8'))` then it throws the above error.

Comment: I tried this `plt.imread("b'/home/atin/test/\xd0\x9e\xd0\x94 \xd0\x94.bmp'")`, then I get following error. `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 18-21: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @AtinGhosh: you should not put quotes around that.. it'd be `plt.imread(b'/home/atin/test/\xd0\x9e\xd0\x94 \xd0\x94.bmp')`. But we already established that that doesn't work.

Comment: yeah my bad, yes it doesn't work, any suggestion, or any other workaround?

Comment: thanks a lot for all the help, I will go with the first solution you posted. I was trying something similar as `encode('utf8', 'surrogateescape')` but missed the `surrogateescape`argument. I do not fully understand what it does, but it works now. Thanks again, it was really helpful.

Comment: @AtinGhosh: I'd expect that to raise a `FileNotFoundError` exception. There is still the possibility that the actual file has some other issue. That said, the best workaround is to *fix your locale*.

Comment: @AtinGhosh: I link to the documentation for error handlers. `surrogateescape` tries to preserve unknown bytes (those that the codec can't handle) by 'hiding' them in a range of Unicode codepoints that you would not normally use in actual text, the low surrogate pair codepoints. When you then encode again, those same codepoints are turned back in to the original byte values.

Comment: sorry for an elementary question, how do I fix my locale, I don't have sudo access to this server, I tried `export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`, but this is not permanent fix I guess. Any suggestion?

Comment: @AtinGhosh: you can set that in your `.bashrc` file, so it is set for all your logins to that machine.

Comment: I fixed the locale by adding `export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"` to my `.bashrc` but still nothing changed. And regarding accepting your answer, I am very new here with respect to asking question, so figuring out stuff, otherwise I would have done that immediately after you posted the answer. :) really appreciate someone like you taking time to write such trivial answer :)